# Double results in mysql command line

Tags: mysql

I run this command via ssh:

`mysql --defaults-extra-file=/login.cnf database < /test.sql`

/test.sql contents:

```
SELECT 1; 
SELECT 1234;
```

I get this response:

```
[root@testvps ~]# mysql --defaults-extra-file=/login.cnf database < /test.sql
1
1
1234
1234
```

Why there is double results? I expect the response should be:

```
1
1234
```

Does it mean that each SELECT query were executed twice?

MySQL version that I am using is `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.11, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`

Thank you in advance for all the answers! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because there is the column name and the corresponding value.

The answer format is the following:

```
+--------+
| Column |
+--------+
| Value  |
+--------+
```